# fetch POST not working on heroku but work locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

So I tried to make a request using

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const CommentForm = (props) => {

const [inputHandler, setInputHandler] = useState();
const [nameHandler, setNameHandler] = useState();

const URL_COMMENT = `https://damp-sierra-44032.herokuapp.com/API/${props.postID}/comment`

const submitValue = async (e) => {
   const data = {name: nameHandler, comment: inputHandler}
   await postComment(data);
   window.location.reload()
}

async function postComment(data) {
    await fetch(URL_COMMENT, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  }


return (
    <div>
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." value={nameHandler} onChange={e => setNameHandler(e.target.value)} required></input>
        <input type="text" name="comment"placeholder={"Write comment here..."} value={inputHandler} onChange={e => setInputHandler(e.target.value)} required></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={submitValue}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}

export default CommentForm
```

to heroku from my React app and when i clicked submit button the heroku log shows

[heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Nhp.png)

but when I tried to request from my app that runs locally (localhost:8000) it works just fine and succesfully creates new comment.
I wonder what's wrong?

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: @epascarello https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Nhp.png

Comment: browser console... What is not working? Also appears you do not cancel the form submission.

Comment: That's not an error. The API endpoint is working. see: https://damp-sierra-44032.herokuapp.com/API/5f9d3e869d653f4dd683aab4/comment What is your issue?

Comment: @epascarello nothing in browser console

Comment: @TinNguyen it failed to create new comment to DB but when I request from my express app that runs locally it succesfully create new comment to DB

Comment: HTTP GET works fine: https://i.imgur.com/sn0nZ2c.png HTTP POST is blocked by CORS https://i.imgur.com/uSgp3YX.png. This is an error message that should have turned up in the browser console.